# copy matlibplot plot image from jupyter lab

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Gurus,

I was trying to copy a python plot from jupyterlab. Although the image looks fine under jupyterlab, it shows a totally black theme after it is pasted to my word doc. Could you please let me know how to solve this? Thx.

My code was

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[1,2,3] 
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

And the image was attached [image]

Comment: Try saving the image as a file and then insert in Word

Comment: I guess [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376153/4124317) I just gave solves this problem directly.

Answer (score 10):

A slightly faster method than what user2036476 has suggested:

1. Hold down shift while right-clicking the plot
2. Select "Copy image"

done

Answer (score 7):

1. Right click on the plot and select "Create New View for Output".
2. Right click the plot in the output view and select "Copy Image" or "Save Image As...".
3. If you do the "Save As" option, there isn't a black edge. If you go the copy/paste route, you can crop out the black edges in an image editor of your choice, or even powerpoint.