# Enable white frames on matplotlib figure/ Disable transparent frames

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, figure, axes

I'm running ipython notebook on a dark theme. When I build a chart on this, the chart is white, but the frame is transparent (hence dark), hiding the ticks which are also dark. Is there a way to make the frame not transparent/ white?

[image: The ticks are barely visible due to the black background.]

The ticks are barely visible due to black background.

How do I solve this? Thanks!

Edit: This is not about changing the colors of axis, ticks/labels, I'm thinking of adding a white background frame, not changing the colors of ticks - it'll be ugly if I just change the color of the ticks because the figure is white

Comment: @Yuca I don't think so, it's not changing the colors of axis, ticks/labels, I'm thinking of adding a white background frame so I don't have to change them - it'll be ugly if I just change the color of the ticks because the figure is white.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14088687/9754169

Comment: sorry for the wrong link, this should be the correct one :) (you need to modify the figure's patch property)

Comment: @Yuca Thanks this solves it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The figure shown in jupyter with the `%matplotlib inline` backend (which is often the default) is created via saving it through `savefig` to a png that is then displayed. `savefig` has an argument `facecolor` which sets the color of the figure background. This can be set to white, e.g. `fig.savefig("name.png", facecolor="w")`.

The options for saving can be adapted in the jupyter configuration. To achieve a white background one can set

```
%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs={'facecolor' : "w"}
```

in a cell prior to showing the plot.

If that is to be used for every notebook, it can also be added to the [ipython configuration file](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html)

```
c = get_config()
c.InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs={'facecolor' : "w"}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried setting `matplotlibrc`, it does not work. It turns out to be an IPython problem!

Answer (score -1):

To have a transparent frame just add the following line after loading matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'none'
```

This did the trick for me!

Comment: The question was about how to make the frame "not transparent"